# How to specify the exact position of floats?

Tags: floats, positioning

How do I specify the exact position of a float?

I am not talking about the [t],[b],[h!] etc operators, I want to specify the exact position of the float, i.e. 15cm from top and 15cm from left.

Regards

Comment: It is rather a contradiction: a float which is not a float.

Comment: @Michael_K: If you want to fix it at that position, than drop the `floating` of the figure, just omit `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` enclosing around your graphics file. If you still need a caption, use `\captionof{figure}[short_caption]{long_caption}` from the `caption` package. The same holds true for any other float, of course, not just `figures`

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer, once I have done that however, what commands would I actually use to place the non-floating figure at a given location?

Comment: Package [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) might help.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke yes thats true I suppose, but you know what I meant (-:

Comment: @Michael_K Hence I've added an additional tag.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke oo I didn't see. Thanks.